# How to get integer value to ResultSet and assign it to an int variable?

Tags: java, jdbc

The int `bookID` is returning the value `0`, it should return `1`. (The first id in the table.) Kindly Assist.

```
public void ID(){

   conn = ConnectDB();

   String sql = "Select Book_ID From Student Biblio";
   try {
       pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       rs = pst.executeQuery();

       if(rs.next()){
        int bookID = rs.getInt(1); //IDTable


       }

   } catch (SQLException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your CREATE statement of the table.

Comment: You are not ordering the table, nor selecting the row with `Book_ID` `1`, so it is quite possible you have a different row as a result.

Comment: ok i have changed the code int BookID1 = rs.getInt("Book_ID"); but the code gives the value 0 to BookID1.

Comment: What is the result you get when you run this SQL on the database?

Comment: Sorry bro, thanks for helping me but i have solved it Thank You.Appreciate Your Concern On This.

Comment: show us  the structure of table.

Answer (score 1):

try this may b it helps you

```
public void ID(){

   conn = ConnectDB();

   String sql = "Select Book_ID From Student Biblio";
   try {
       pst = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
       rs = pst.executeQuery();

       while(rs.next()){
        int bookID = rs.getInt("Book_ID"); //IDTable


       }

   } catch (SQLException ex) {
       Logger.getLogger(Student.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of if try using while loop and check if the row of the table.

Comment: ok i have changed the code int BookID1 = rs.getInt("Book_ID"); but the code gives the value 0 to BookID1 and used while loop but it gives value 0 to BookID1, it should give the value 1.